# Are questions about checking correctness of code on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As I know, questions about non-working code can fit on Stack Overflow, while already working code should be on Code Review. But what about code where I'm not sure it is working?

I just found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055123/java-program-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-word-in-string) that was about checking the correctness of a code. I guess it is asking if there is some missing cases to handle for the input.

Is this type of question on-topic?

Comment: If one is not sure that it works, maybe writing some tests would make more sense. IMO it's better than scrambling together a question and throwing it on SO.

Comment: Just FYI, the question you linked to has been deleted. So I'm guessing that it was *not* considered on-topic.

Comment: As an aside, "correctness of codes", "correctness of a code", there is something grammatically wrong about that.

Comment: If the code works *as far as you know* and you just have a healthy curiosity about any unanticipated edge cases in which it might not work, that doesn't disqualify it from Code Review. If you have no idea whether it works and you want someone to spell it out for you, that definitely disqualifies it. In my experience, questions about potentially working code will clearly fall in one or the other category; there's not that much gray area in between.

Comment: ...how do you not know if your code works? Try running it.

Comment: "I'm not sure" is anything but a *clear problem statement*.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem with this is that it doesn't really have a *good* answer to it.  Whether or not the code works, given some constraints, is either **yes** or **no**.

This is where things start to get uncomfortable.

At this point, after the definitive answer on whether or not the code works, the OP would like some sort of dialog on what could be improved.  Now, this could be something as simple as mixing up a value somewhere; it could be as broad as, "This entire code is broken beyond repair and only a rewrite will save it."

This in my mind makes these questions **too broad.**  There's too many ways that this code could or could not work.

The only real salvation to this type of question would be if the OP could narrow down the problem space; instead of asking if this code is OK in general, they could ask why the code wouldn't work in these specific cases, and provide those cases in addition to their code.  The key critical thing here:  **we can't allow for a dialog on the state of their code.**  We need them to narrow their question and be prepared for an answer with respect to that scope.

Comment: Would it be suitable on Programmers.SE?

Comment: @AbAppletic:  No.

Comment: But maybe on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. They say "The quality of your working code with regards to: Correctness in unanticipated cases"

Comment: @ThomasWeller:  Probably not, since it doesn't appear to satisfy [one of the particular criterion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of reviewed code, in that it is actual, real code.

Comment: @Makoto: oh, they review quite much over there. You can tag as [beginner].

Comment: @ThomasWeller:  Maybe.  I'm always gun-shy about sending questions over there since I don't fully understand what's on-topic at all times, and most of the questions that are pitched to go over there are terrible.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I recommend you to not blindly recommend sites to post questions unless you are not alien to their specific scopes and quality expectations. Code Review is for code that you know that works, it does what you meant it to do, and want a third opinion about how to make it more resilient, reusable and clearer (aka code not written while you were drunk).

Comment: @Braiam: I don't see how I blindly recommended something. I even cited parts of the using instructions: "of your working code". Also, I wanted to give a suggestion to AbApplectic, not necessarily to the OP and I definitely don't want the deleted question to go there. But I think too few people are aware that CodeReview exists. On any site, posters should check the guidelines.

Comment: @ThomasWeller just make sure that when you raise awareness of codereview on SO, raise awareness to [this too](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: thanks. I wasn't aware of it. Starring it for reuse

Answer (score -2):

You should totally drop that and try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

It's a Stack Exchange specifically for this purpose.

Comment: [Careful; you're walking into a landmine there.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)  Don't just go up and recommend Code Review without being certain the question will fit on there.

Comment: @Makoto oh - I didn't read the comments in your answer. Maybe there should have been some content in your answer explicitly saying why Code Review may not be a good fit.