# Is question like "Is this few lines of code OK?" need to close if the root cause and answers are simple?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm having hesitation about closing question:

[Is this JavaScript code OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719039/is-this-javascript-code-ok)

On one hand, even the OP don't know if there is any problem about the code. On the other hand, this question seems doesn't belong to the case like [Are questions about checking correctness of code on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336375/are-questions-about-checking-correctness-of-code-on-topic), because this time the code is much shorter, and the root cause is simple, which is already a narrowed scope in stead of a broad question.

My question is, is this kind of questions need to close? If so, what is the close reason?

Comment: Even though the answers are simple, the question is terrible. What defines as OK? It'll certainly work; but their code doesn't really make sense. Askers need to define explicitly what they mean by 'working' and 'not working'. Are they asking if it's possible to pass arguments not defined? Are they asking how to change the text? Are they asking whether or not it's good coding practice? Who knows? They just gave a code dump and asked people to fix it based on no 'passing' criteria.

Comment: Should be closed as "Unclear what you're asking"